# C# Merging .dll files with ILMerge

Tags: c#, dll, merge, ilmerge

I am facing a problem with ILMerge. I have 4 dll files required for my app but I merged them into 1 with ILMerge using the following syntax:

ilmerge /out:merged.dll lib1.dll lib2.dll lib3.dll lib4.dll

Then I added the file merged.dll as a reference in my solution and removed the other 4. But my application still fails to load when the other dll files are not in the directory of the application.

Did I miss any step? It doesn't make any sense to me why it wouldn't work..

Answer (score 2):

Fail on my part. I was testing on an older build of my application, which explains why it didn't work. The above steps will work fine so I hope this may be useful to someone.